# How to delete an item in list json localstorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, local-storage

How to delete an item in list json array localstorage?

In localstorage example:
`key: notes
value: ["car", "apple", "orange", "banana"]`

e.g. I want to remove only `orange` in `notes`

I get this code from https://codepen.io/xszaboj/pen/dOXEey?editors=1010

I try add this function delNote() but not work

This full code

```js
function addNote(){
  var data = localStorage.getItem("notes")
  var notes = null;
  if(data != null)
    {
   notes = JSON.parse(data);
    }
  if(notes == null){
    notes = [];
  }
  notes.push($("#note").val());
  localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notes));
  refreshNotes();
}
function refreshNotes(){
  var notesElement =$("#notes");
  notesElement.empty();
  var notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes"));
  if(notes != null){
    for(var i = 0; i< notes.length; i++){
      var note = notes[i];
      notesElement.append("<li onclick='delNote(this.innerHTML)'>"+note+"</li>");
    }
  }
}
function delNote(e){
  var notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes"));
  delete notes[e];refreshNotes();
}

$(function(){
  refreshNotes();
  
  $("#add").click(function(){
    addNote();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="note" />
<button id="add">add note</button>

<ul id="notes">
  
  </ul>
```

How to delete an item in list json array localstorage?

Comment: at this point I think it's easier to learn Elm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Parse json
let notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes"))
// Get index of object
const index = notes.indexOf(obj)
// Splice the array at the index of your object
notes.splice(index, 1)
// Save back to localStorage
localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notes))
```

Comment: your previous answers were it is working. `const index = notes.indexOf(obj)`